# How to properly use array_key_exists

Tags: php, arrays, array-push, array-key-exists

```
$array = json_decode('[{"1234567":1368356071},{"7654321":1368356071}, etc, etc]');
$array2 = array(array(1234567 => time()), array(7654321 => time()));
   foreach($array2 as $key){
      if(!array_key_exists(key($key),$array))
           array_push($array, $key);
   }
```

Why are $keys that are in $array still getting pushed through to $array?

Pretty much I'm trying to prevent duplicate keys from getting pushed into $array..

Comment: error in code foreach($array2 as $key){    replace foreach($array2 as $key => $val){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

You had three problems

1) You were decoding array into stdObject, it should be set true to return it to array

2) You need to loop array as  foreach($array2 as $key => $val)

3) Pass as $array[0] in array_key_exists function

```
  $array = json_decode('[{"1234567":1368356071}]', true);

$array2 = array(1234567 => time(), 7654321 => time());
//echo count($array);
foreach($array2 as $key => $val){


    if(!array_key_exists($key,$array[0]))
        array_push($array, $key);
}
echo count($array);
```

Comment: foreach($array2 as $key => $val){ seems to be pushing the index not the key

Comment: Pretty much I'm trying to prevent duplicate keys from getting pushed into $array..

Answer (score 1):

Because `$array` is 2 dimensional array and `$array2` is 1D array, use below code

```
<?php

$array = json_decode('[{"1234567":1368356071}]',true);
print_r($array);
$array2 = array(array(1234567 => time()), array(7654321 => time()));
echo count($array);
foreach($array2 as $key){    

  if(!array_key_exists($key[0],$array[0]))
       array_push($array, $key);
}
echo count($array);
```

?>

**Output**

```
1
2
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/9UE6so79)

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar how is array2 1D, isn't it the same as array but with 2 keys?

Comment: @GameDevGuru Yes array2 is with 2 keys but a 1 Dimensional array.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Oh okay i understand. My code had a mistake. Array2 is also 2D

Comment: @YogeshSuthar This works but not very well. What if i had multiple values in array1? [{"1234567":1368356071}, {"7654321":1368356071}] $array[0] searches only the first one..

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Pretty much I'm trying to prevent duplicate keys from getting pushed into $array..

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `isset` works faster than the function `array_key_exists`.
You should use `isset` if you don't have to tell **Undefined** from **NULL**.

array_key_exists:

```
array_key_exists($key,$array);
```

isset:

```
isset($array[$key]);
```

Tested on Ideone:
http://ideone.com/m1Do1d

---

To prevent duplicate keys from getting pushed into $array, it works with this code:

```
<?php

$array = json_decode('[{"1234567":1368356071}]', true);
$array2 = array(array(1234567 => time()), array(7654321 => time()));

var_dump(
    '$array (before)', $array,
    '$array2', $array2
);

foreach ($array2 as $item2) {    
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (isset($item[key($item2)])) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $array[] = $item2;
}

var_dump(
    '$array (after)', $array
);
```

Result:

```
string(15) "$array (before)"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1234567]=>
    int(1368356071)
  }
}
string(7) "$array2"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1234567]=>
    int(1368650316)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [7654321]=>
    int(1368650316)
  }
}
string(14) "$array (after)"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1234567]=>
    int(1368356071)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [7654321]=>
    int(1368650316)
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't that only checking if that index is set? I need to search an array to see if a key already exists before pushing

Comment: Pretty much I'm trying to prevent duplicate keys from getting pushed into $array..

Comment: Needless to say, you should just replace array_key_exists to isset, in other answers' codes...

Comment: And you don't need to use array_push. array_push is required only if you push several items at once.